# Lightning : Select not storing changed data

Tags: lightning, aura, aura-attribute, aura-iteration

The issue is that when I click on save, the data is not being saved... In the same object, I have a checkbox wich is being correctly saved, so I don't know what could be happening.
I have next select:

```
<td><div class="slds-truncate">
          <lightning:select  aura:id="selectId" name="FormerReason"  label="Select a Former Reason:"  >
              <option  value="{!account.FormerReason}">{!account.Former_Reason__c}</option>
              <aura:iteration   items="{!v.options}" var="option">
                <option text="{!option.label}" value="{!option.value}" selected="{!option.selected}"></option>/>
              </aura:iteration>
          </lightning:select>
          </div>
      </td>
```

being charged with this values:

```
loadOptions: function (component, event, helper) {
    var opts = [
        { value: "--None--", label: "--None--" },
        { value: "option1", label: "option1" },
        { value: "option2", label: "option2" }
     ];
     component.set("v.options", opts);
}
```

And a save button :

```
<td><button type="button" onclick="{!c.saveRecord}" >Save</button></td>
```

This is the save logic :

```
 saveRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
    debugger;
    var action = component.get("c.saveRelation");
    debugger;

    action.setParams({
        "account" : component.get("v.accounts")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
        component.set("v.editMode",'true');
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

and Apex recieving method:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static boolean saveRelation (List<AccountContactRelation> account){
    try{
        update account;
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple list that is not bound to any particular data. You need to bind it to the value it should represent:

```
      <lightning:select  aura:id="selectId" value="{!account.Former_Reason__c}"
         name="FormerReason"  label="Select a Former Reason:"  >
```

Without this binding, you won't get the result you expect. I also suspect that you do not need to actually use the iteration; you could have simply set `options` to the values you want to use, which is a lot easier to bind to dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was exactly that, I just was needing some sleep to see this at myself . Ha.